How to prevent SwiftUI view to redraw every time on Published property update?
I have a LandingView that has a viewModel which is an ObservableObject. LandingView loads some CardViews dynamically and passes a model object (Binding property).
CardView further nests four different subviews and passes the attributes needed through Binding. There are text fields in those four subviews. When the user updates the textfield data, the updated data travels back to viewModel through Binding.
Now the problem is that when the user keys in a single character in any of those text fields, the viewmodel is updated and hence the LandingView is re-drawn which leads to the text field losing focus and user has to tap on the text field again.
Is there a way to fix this? I know that I can fix it by getting rid of the Binding properties and have some other mechanism to maintain data flow. But, can I fix it in the current setup itself?
Thanks much in advance!!!!
struct LandingView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = LandingViewModel(gridDataArray: [])
    @State var name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        ZStack {
            Color(red: 242/255, green: 242/255, blue: 242/255)
            listView
               .background(Color.white)
               .padding()
        }
        
    }
 
    
    private var listView: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(Array(viewModel.gridDataArray.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, element in
                    CardView(dataModel: $viewModel.gridDataArray[index])
                        .equatable()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: CardView, rhs: CardView) -> Bool {
        lhs.dataModel.hashValue == rhs.dataModel.hashValue
    }
    
    @Binding var dataModel: LandingViewDataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            NavyBlueView(productName: $dataModel.productName, 
                         productId: $dataModel.productId,
                         productLabel: dataModel.productLabel)
            YellowView(weightedProductPrice: $dataModel.weightedProductPrice, 
                       wacSubWACUnitPrice: $dataModel.wacSubWACUnitPrice,
                       pvpUnitPrice: $dataModel.pvpUnitPrice)
            
            SkyBlueView(weightedPriceUsagePercent: $dataModel.weightedPriceUsagePercent,
                        wacSubWACUnitPricePercent: $dataModel.wacSubWACUnitPricePercent,
                        pvpUnitPricePercent: $dataModel.pvpUnitPricePercent,
                        totalPercent: $dataModel.totalPercent)
            GreenView(weightedPriceCalculated: $dataModel.weightedPriceCalculated,
                      wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated: $dataModel.wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated,
                      pvpUnitPriceCalculated: $dataModel.pvpUnitPriceCalculated,
                      totalCalculated: $dataModel.totalCalculated)
        }
    }
}

struct NavyBlueView: View {
    @Binding var productName: String
    @Binding var productId: String?
    var productLabel: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(productLabel)
                .padding()
                .padding(.bottom, -10)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            HStack {
                Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                TextField("Product Name", text: $productName)
                    .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
            .frame(width: 500, height: 35)
            .padding(.leading, 15)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
            
            HStack {
                Text("      ")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Text("Weighted Price")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Text("WAC/SubWAC Unit Price")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Text("340B/PVP Unit Price")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Text("Total")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
        }
        .background(Color(red: 41 / 255, green: 78 / 255, blue: 124 / 255))
        .clipShape(.rect(
            topLeadingRadius: 10,
            bottomLeadingRadius: 0,
            bottomTrailingRadius: 0,
            topTrailingRadius: 10)
        )
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

struct YellowView: View {
    @Binding var weightedProductPrice: String
    @Binding var wacSubWACUnitPrice: String
    @Binding var pvpUnitPrice: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Group {
                Text("Product Price")
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                    TextField("Product price", text: $weightedProductPrice)
                        .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
                .frame(height: 35)
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                    TextField("Product price", text: $wacSubWACUnitPrice)
                        .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
                .frame(height: 35)
                .padding(10)
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                    TextField("Product price", text: $pvpUnitPrice)
                        .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
                .frame(height: 35)
                
                Text("")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 35)
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color(red: 238/255, green: 238/255, blue: 239/255))
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(red: 255/255, green: 254/255, blue: 185/255))
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

struct SkyBlueView: View {
    @Binding var weightedPriceUsagePercent: String
    @Binding var wacSubWACUnitPricePercent: String
    @Binding var pvpUnitPricePercent: String
    @Binding var totalPercent: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Group {
                Text("Usage %")
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                    TextField("Percentage", text: $weightedPriceUsagePercent)
                        .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
                .frame(height: 35)
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                    TextField("Percentage", text: $wacSubWACUnitPricePercent)
                        .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
                .frame(height: 35)
                .padding(10)
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                    TextField("Percentage", text: $pvpUnitPricePercent)
                        .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
                .frame(height: 35)
                
                ZStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                        TextField("", text: $totalPercent)
                            .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    }
                    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
                    .frame(height: 35)
                    .border((Color(red: 183/255, green: 181/255, blue: 182/255)), width: 2)
                    .padding(10)

                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 35)
                .padding(10)
                .background(Color(red: 238/255, green: 238/255, blue: 239/255))
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(red: 199/255, green: 229/255, blue: 243/255))
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}


struct GreenView: View {
    @Binding var weightedPriceCalculated: String
    @Binding var wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated: String
    @Binding var pvpUnitPriceCalculated: String
    @Binding var totalCalculated: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Group {
                Text("Weighted Price")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Text(weightedPriceCalculated)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Text(wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Text(pvpUnitPriceCalculated)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                
                ZStack {
                    Text(totalCalculated)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 25)
                .padding(10)
                .background(Color(red: 76/255, green: 174/255, blue: 234/255))
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(red: 195/255, green: 231/255, blue: 145/255))
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}


final class LandingViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var gridDataArray: [LandingViewDataModel] = []
    
    init(gridDataArray: [LandingViewDataModel]) {
        self.gridDataArray = gridDataArray
        self.gridDataArray.append(LandingViewDataModel(productLabel: "Endo Product",
                                                       productName: "Endo product something",
                                                       productId: "Endo product ID",
                                                       weightedProductPrice: "122.43",
                                                       weightedPriceUsagePercent: "30",
                                                       weightedPriceCalculated: "",
                                                       wacSubWACUnitPrice: "111.33",
                                                       wacSubWACUnitPricePercent: "20",
                                                       wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated: "",
                                                       pvpUnitPrice: "222.33",
                                                       pvpUnitPricePercent: "50",
                                                       pvpUnitPriceCalculated: "",
                                                       totalPercent: "",
                                                       totalCalculated: ""))
        
        self.gridDataArray.append(LandingViewDataModel(productLabel: "Competitor 1",
                                                       productName: "Competitor 1",
                                                       productId: nil,
                                                       weightedProductPrice: "198.43",
                                                       weightedPriceUsagePercent: "10",
                                                       weightedPriceCalculated: "",
                                                       wacSubWACUnitPrice: "987.33",
                                                       wacSubWACUnitPricePercent: "70",
                                                       wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated: "",
                                                       pvpUnitPrice: "876.33",
                                                       pvpUnitPricePercent: "20",
                                                       pvpUnitPriceCalculated: "",
                                                       totalPercent: "",
                                                       totalCalculated: ""))
        
        self.gridDataArray.append(LandingViewDataModel(productLabel: "Competitor 2",
                                                       productName: "Competitor 2",
                                                       productId: nil,
                                                       weightedProductPrice: "445.43",
                                                       weightedPriceUsagePercent: "40",
                                                       weightedPriceCalculated: "",
                                                       wacSubWACUnitPrice: "432.33",
                                                       wacSubWACUnitPricePercent: "20",
                                                       wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated: "",
                                                       pvpUnitPrice: "456.33",
                                                       pvpUnitPricePercent: "40",
                                                       pvpUnitPriceCalculated: "",
                                                       totalPercent: "",
                                                       totalCalculated: ""))
        
    }
}

struct LandingViewDataModel: Hashable, Equatable {
    let productLabel: String
    var productName: String
    var productId: String?
    
    var weightedProductPrice: String {
        didSet {
            calculate()
        }
    }
    var weightedPriceUsagePercent: String {
        didSet {
            calculate()
        }
    }
    var weightedPriceCalculated: String
    
    var wacSubWACUnitPrice: String {
        didSet {
            calculate()
        }
    }
    var wacSubWACUnitPricePercent: String {
        didSet {
            calculate()
        }
    }
    var wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated: String
    
    var pvpUnitPrice: String {
        didSet {
            calculate()
        }
    }
    var pvpUnitPricePercent: String {
        didSet {
            calculate()
        }
    }
    var pvpUnitPriceCalculated: String
    
    var totalPercent: String
    var totalCalculated: String
}

extension LandingViewDataModel {
    private mutating func calculate() {
        if let flotPrice = Float(weightedProductPrice), let percentage = Float(weightedPriceUsagePercent)  {
            weightedPriceCalculated = "\(flotPrice * (percentage / 100))"
        }
        
        if let flotPrice = Float(wacSubWACUnitPrice), let percentage = Float(wacSubWACUnitPricePercent)  {
            wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated = "\(flotPrice * (percentage / 100))"
        }
        
        if let flotPrice = Float(pvpUnitPrice), let percentage = Float(pvpUnitPricePercent)  {
            pvpUnitPriceCalculated = "\(flotPrice * (percentage / 100))"
        }
        
        if let weightedPriceUsagePercent = Int(weightedPriceUsagePercent),
           let wacSubWACUnitPricePercent = Int(wacSubWACUnitPricePercent),
           let pvpUnitPricePercent = Int(pvpUnitPricePercent) {
            totalPercent = "\(weightedPriceUsagePercent + wacSubWACUnitPricePercent + pvpUnitPricePercent)"
        }
        
        if let weightedPriceCalculated = Float(weightedPriceCalculated),
           let wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated = Float(wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated),
           let pvpUnitPriceCalculated = Float(pvpUnitPriceCalculated) {
            totalCalculated = "\(weightedPriceCalculated + wacSubWACUnitPriceCalculated + pvpUnitPriceCalculated)"
        }
    }
}



Now the problem is that the when a user types a single character in any of those text fields..., there are no TextField in your code where you say you have your problem.
I suspect you are using .onChange instead of .onSubmit.
Show some code where you have the TextField.
Note, remove your static func == ..., views already conform to EquatableView.

I updated with the subviews that hold the text fields which I initially didn't include to reduce the size of question.
@workingdogsupportUkraine I am not using .onChange. Agreed about the EquatableView comment. I was just experimenting many things.

I already tried removing the @Binding property from CardView and that fixes the textfield losing focus issue. But I don't really want that as my viewModel won't get updated with the latest data from text fields.

Try making LandingViewDataModel a class instead of a struct.  You are using a mutating function on your struct, which means you are continually creating new instances of it.

The ForEach(Array( Enumerated common mistake might have got you a downvote

I agree with @malhal here. The effect is, that typing a character causes the CardView to change its identity. And this causes it to completely reset its "memory" and build from scratch, which removes the focus.
Personal note: the downvote is in no way helpful and not justified. This error is subtle and requires advanced knowledge how the SwiftUI system works.

@malhal Thanks. You are pointing me a right direction!! What is the alternative for enumerated if I want an index?

Index your model data yourself before you describe its UI with View structs

In order to solve this issue, you have to make quite a bit of changes to your original design.

Ensure that when using ForEach, List, etc., the element type (aka LandingViewDataModel in the passed random access container conforms to Identifiable.

Avoid mutating the view state (aka LandingViewDataModel) directly - i.e. your mutating function calculate(). Instead move the logic into the ObservableObject (aka LandingViewModel).

The view should be a "function of state". Triple this.

A view should never change its view state directly in the "source of truth", aka your view model (means, don't use two-way bindings).

From #2, #3 and #4 follows: when designing SwiftUI views, avoid using two-way bindings unless absolutely necessary. Instead use a combination "let values" to define the view state in addition to closure variables which define the "commands" (intents) which can be sent from the view to the ObservableObject which handles these commands. So, instead of passing down a Binding, pass down the const value (which represents the "view's state") and closures which get called when a user-initiated event happens (i.e. changing the text of an EditField, tapping a button, etc.).

In order to let SwiftUI to perform optimal diffing, avoid using functions which return a View from within the body. Instead use a SwiftUI view. The best practice is to make many smaller views, instead of few large views.


Tip:
Collect and list all events that can happen in your whole view. Then, create an enum:
typealias ID = LandingViewDataModel.ID
enum Event {
    case textFieldXyzChanged(id: ID, text: String)
    case focusChanged(id: ID)
    case submitButtonTapped(id: ID, payload: Data)
    ... 
}

(note: since your events are associated to a certain element in the view model's array, you need to send the ID of the element with the event, so that the view model knows, which element is it associated with)
Then, you only need one method in the ObservableObject:
send(_ event: Event)

which is able to handle all events that can happen in this use case. That way, you need to pass down only one single closure function down to your views and subviews.

Thank you so much! I really appreciate the long descriptive answer and valuable tips. Actually I was considering this approach (kind of long shot) but I wanted to check if there is a way to solve it using @Binding itself. I will give this a try.

In your case, you cannot avoid SwiftUI Bindings, totally - since TextFields requires it. But at the root view level, you should avoid them and pass the model as a let constant, and a closure which calls viewModel.send(.someEvent). Also, you need to pass an ID in every event which is the ID of the current element in the array where the event is associated with: enum Event {     case doSomething(id: UUID) } 

Yes! I am on it.

I fixed it per your last comment. It's all good now. Removed the @Published wrapper from my view model array and removed Binding from the root level. Instead just passing the simple model object to CardView. I have marked this as the accepted answer. Maybe I will add my changes as a separate answer as well, just for brevity.

@RashmiRanjanMallick Sure, please post your improved version. ;)
